# File attachment field plugin for posts

Tags: plugins, attachment-fields-to-edit

I need to add a field in the posts to add attachments like PDF doc jpg PNG ... and then have it automatically displayed under the post.  Do you know of any plugins that already do this, I've tried a few, but they haven't been updated in a long time or don't work perfectly